# Re: Regex - How do I match a word within the first 10 words of a text?

Tags: regex

**Consider following string as an Example Text:**

This hook rack holds my purse on the wall with no problems. The hooks are elegant-looking, with a brushed **metal** look that lends itself well to all kinds of decor.

I want to match "**metal**" but only if it appears in the first 10 words of the text. Is that possible to formulate?

Comment: which language?

Comment: It worths mentioning that you are using Simple Regex Language

Comment: Yes. I am using Simple Regular Expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another simple solution that should work:

```
^(?:\w+\s*){0,9}(metal)
```

From the beginning of the string `^`, match at most 9 words followed by the word `metal`. For example, this would match 3 words followed by metal (metal is the 4th word), or 7 words followed by metal (metal is the 8th word), but not 10 words followed by metal (metal is the 11th word).

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/tj9oaS/1

Comment: This is much more sensible.. my brain totally over-complicated it for some reason :)

Comment: @jaytea Your answer was awesome though!

Comment: @omijn thanks, very kind of you to say :P I would say "awesome-ly overkill!" haha